# Почему не увеличивается переменная?

Tags: c#, sql

Здравствуйте.

Что в этом коде происходит, сначала идет считывание ID, запрос сортирует их по увеличению... после чего ID передается переменной timer. Далее другой запрос, ищет поле URL где ID = переменной timer, он считывает и передает URL в label1, и в самом конце, идёт увеличение переменной timer на 1, чтобы при следующем обращении к таймеру считывалась не та же ячейка, а другая.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static string host, database, user, password, strProvider;
        public int timer = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            host = "91.227.16.13";
            password = "15*35*";
            user = "h2*199_di*a";
            database = "h2*199_*est";

            strProvider = "Data Source=" + host + ";Database=" + database + ";User ID=" + user + ";Password=" + password;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MySqlConnection cnt = new MySqlConnection(strProvider);
            try
            {
                cnt.Open();
                MySqlCommand cmd3 = cnt.CreateCommand();
                MySqlCommand command = cnt.CreateCommand();

                command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM t_links ORDER BY ID DESC";

                cmd3.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM t_links WHERE ID = " + timer;

                MySqlDataReader readID = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (readID.Read())
                {
                    timer = Convert.ToInt32(readID["ID"]);
                }
                readID.Close();

                MySqlDataReader readURK = cmd3.ExecuteReader();
                while (readURK.Read())
                {
                    label1.Text = "URL: " + readURK["URL"].ToString();
                }
                readURK.Close();

                this.Text = timer.ToString();

                timer++;
            }
            finally
            {
                cnt.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Программа не увеличивает переменную... и не передает URL в label1. Ниже скриншот базы откуда я пытаюсь брать значения :

[image]

PS Да, и скажите, на какой хостинг картинок надо заливать картинки, чтобы хэшкод не как ссылку их воспринимал, а как картинку?

Comment: Чтобы вставить картинку, воспользуйтесь кнопкой вставки в редакторе.

Answer (score 2):

```
            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM t_links ORDER BY ID DESC"; // Команда на считывание всех записей из базы

            cmd3.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM t_links WHERE ID = " + timer;

            MySqlDataReader readID = command.ExecuteReader(); // Выполняем команду
            while (readID.Read())
            {
                timer = Convert.ToInt32(readID["ID"]); // Присваиваем таймеру значение максимального id
            }
            readID.Close();
```

`timer = Convert.ToInt32(readID["ID"]);` происходит при каждом тике, поэтому может таймер и увеличивается, но потом опять устанавливается равным максимальному id.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static string host, database, user, password, strProvider;
        public int timer = 0;
        MySqlConnection cnt;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            host = "11.111.11.11";
            password = "1111111111";
            user = "11111111111";
            database = "111111111111";

            strProvider = "Data Source=" + host + ";Database=" + database + ";User ID=" + user + ";Password=" + password;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            cnt = new MySqlConnection(strProvider);
            cnt.Open();
            MySqlCommand command = cnt.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "SELECT max(id) as `id` FROM t_links";
            timer = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());

            timer1.Enabled = true;
            timer1.Start();

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd3 = cnt.CreateCommand();

                cmd3.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM t_links WHERE ID = " + timer;

                MySqlDataReader readURK = cmd3.ExecuteReader();

                while (readURK.Read())
                {
                    label1.Text = "URL: " + readURK["URL"].ToString();
                }
                readURK.Close();

                this.Text = timer.ToString();

                timer++;
            }
            finally
            {
                cnt.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Только всё равно я не могу понять, зачем считывать из базы записи с id больше максимального. Их ведь там нет :-)

Дополнено:

Тогда лучше сделай так

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static string host, database, user, password, strProvider;
        public int timer = 0;
        MySqlConnection cnt;
        MySqlDataReader readURK;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            host = "11.111.11.11";
            password = "1111111111";
            user = "11111111111";
            database = "111111111111";

            strProvider = "Data Source=" + host + ";Database=" + database + ";User ID=" + user + ";Password=" + password;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            cnt = new MySqlConnection(strProvider);
            cnt.Open();

            MySqlCommand command = cnt.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM t_links ORDER BY id";
            readURK = command.ExecuteReader();

            timer1.Enabled = true;
            timer1.Start();

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(readURK.Read())
            {
                label1.Text = "URL: " + readURK["URL"].ToString();
            }else{
                timer1.Stop();  // Стопим таймер когда записи закончились
            }

        }
    }
}
```

P.S. зачем ты опубликовал свои логины и пароли? :-)

Comment: Программа должа работать по принципу авто-сёрфинга, считала ID передала его label, после подождала интервал таймера, опять считала но уже не тот что был раньше, а тот что был раньше + 1. Ну как мне сказали, у меня идет считывание **самого маленького ID**, и программа должна постепенно(по срабатыванию таймера) доходить до максимального ID

Comment: Ну, тогда

    command.CommandText = "SELECT min(id) as `id` FROM t_links";

`order by` то я загнул маленько, щас исправлю.

Comment: УРА!! **ВСЁ РАБОТАЕТ!!!!** ЕСЛИ БЫ ВЫ ЗНАЛИ, СКОЛЬКО Я ПЫТАЛСЯ ИСПРАВИТЬ ОШИБКУ... скажите, что вы именно заменили (хочу понять..) Прочитайте первый пост, я закрасил данные.

Comment: А вот ещё вопрос, посмотрите на таблицу, там есть пропуск... ID 77 потом сразу идет 79.. как в таком случае поступить? Чтобы прога перескочила на 80?

Comment: Используй код из дополненного ответа.

Он просто обходит имеющиеся строки без лишних запросов к базе. Там всё намного проще.

Comment: Не я перепробовал все коды... не работает, он просматривает ID 77, после смотри "ага ID 78 нету, и останавливает таймер", а как сделать чтобы он остановил таймер до тех пор пока не нашёл следующий ID?