# Максимальное и минимальное значение в базе

Tags: c#

Всем привет, вот скажите у меня база такого типа:

[image]

Вот структура БД

[image]

Так вот, у меня есть таймер в программе (которая работает по принципу автоматического просмотра сайта), который должен сначала определить минимальное значение в БД (ID), т.е по скрину это 84, а потом вычислить максимальный, т.е 111, а потому программа получала минимальный ID просматривала его, например, 10 секунд, после перешла не на 85, а 107. Так вот как это сделать? Чтобы пробелов не осталось? Очень интересно, я по началу хотел сделать так:

```
timerSpawn--;
labelTimer.Text = "Таймер: " + timerSpawn;
if (timerSpawn == 0)
{
    timerSpawn = 10;

    MySqlConnection cnt = new MySqlConnection(strProvider);
    try
    {
        cnt.Open();

        MySqlCommand cmd = cnt.CreateCommand();
        MySqlCommand cmd2 = cnt.CreateCommand();

        cmd2.CommandText = "UPDATE t_links SET looking = looking -'" + statusbase + "' WHERE URL='" + URL + "'";
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE t_user SET balance = balance + '" + statusbase + "' WHERE username='" + textUserName.Text + "' and pass='" + Convert.ToString(textPassword.Text) + "'";
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MySqlCommand cmd3 = cnt.CreateCommand();
        MySqlCommand commandMaxixum = cnt.CreateCommand();
        MySqlCommand commandMinimum = cnt.CreateCommand();
        commandMinimum.CommandText = "SELECT min(id) as `id` FROM t_links";
        MySqlDataReader readMin = commandMinimum.ExecuteReader();
        while (readMin.Read())
        {
            minValue = Convert.ToInt32 (readMin["ID"].ToString ());
        }
        readMin.Close();

        commandMaxixum.CommandText = "SELECT max(id) as `id` FROM t_links";
        MySqlDataReader readerMax = commandMaxixum.ExecuteReader();
        while (readerMax.Read())
        {
            if (timer > Convert.ToInt32(readerMax["ID"]))
            {
                timer = minValue ;
            }
        }
        readerMax.Close();

        cmd3.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM t_links WHERE ID = " + timer;

        MySqlDataReader readURK = cmd3.ExecuteReader();

        if (readURK.Read())
        {
            labelUrl.Text = "URL: " + readURK["URL"].ToString();
            URL = readURK["URL"].ToString();
            webBrowser1.Navigate(URL);

            readURK.Close();
            statusNow.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            statusNow.Text = "Средства зачислены";
        }
        timer++;
    }
    finally
    {
        cnt.Close();
    }
```

А оно почему-то не работает, пожалуйста, помогите эта ошибка у меня уже неделю висит и не могу исправить... кто более опытный, пожалуйста, помогите исправить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас какая-то невероятно странная архитектура с последовательным перебором и переменной `timer`, никак не понимаю почему вы делаете именно так? Можно же ПРОСТО ВЫБРАТЬ ИЗ БАЗЫ **ПРИСУТСТВУЮЩИЕ ТАМ ЗНАЧЕНИЯ** и пройтись по ним в цикле. У вас из базы последовательно выберется 84, 107, 111 и без всяких счётчиков и таймеров. Сделайте по аналогии [с вот этим ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/75859/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F), и будет работать у вас авто-серфинг...